# Surface Integral over scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm stuck on this question and not sure how to approach it.

A metallic surface **S** is in the shape of a hemisphere

$z$=$\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$    ,$0\leq x^2$+$y^2$$\leq R^2$

if the mass density of the metal per unit area is given by $m(x,y,z)$=$x^2$+$y^2$ Find the total mass of **S**.

Answer (score 0):

Total mass of **S** is given by
$$\mathrm{
\iint_{S}m\;\color{blue}{dS}}
$$
Using [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (physics convension) this integral can be written as
$$\mathrm{
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi\over2} R^2\sin^2\theta\;\color{blue}{R^2\sin\theta\;d\theta\;d\phi}=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^4
}$$